# Wrong coordinates in data when projecting in world map (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, coordinates, maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the proper coordinate reference system with two sets of data using different measurements or too convert one system into another](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33852/how-to-find-the-proper-coordinate-reference-system-with-two-sets-of-data-using-d)

I'm fairly new to the GIS world, but I'm doing a project with noise calculations. My dataset is in shapefile and I would like to add a map to my project, so people can see where in the world the project is situated.

But, when I'm adding a map through the OpenLayers plugin my project is situated just south of Nigeria and my project is in Denmark! CRS is WGS 84, EPSG:4326.

How can I change the coordinates of my project so I can add a map to the project?

And, if anyone has a suggestion as to which OpenLayers I should prefer, please say so...

I'm using QGIS 1.8, Lisboa on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Openlayers plugin, your project CRS **must** be in EPSSG:3857 (Google Mercator). Your **data** layers may have a different CRS. You can check it by rightlick on the layer, `Set CRS for Layer`.

You should check `On the fly projection` in `Settings->Project Settings`, CRS Tab.

For choosing a suitable openlayer, I would suggest Openstreetmap, because Google may not like extensive use of their tiles without using their own API, as well as in publications.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the CRS to EPSG:3857 (Pseudo Mercator) and set up the Openstreetmap, but still I don't get any projections of the layers. The Google Mercator is called EPSG:900913. I have also checked "on the fly". The layers are in correct order. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think it's the coordinates of the project that's wrong here. My layers are still south of Nigeria. So maybe I need to transform the coordinates?

Comment: Metadata of 1 layer:
In layer spatial reference system units : xMin,yMin -233766.08,335966.39 : xMax,yMax -231461.94,340192.04
Layer Spatial Reference System:
+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,-0,-0,-0,0 +units=m +no_defs

Comment: This layer should have EPSG:23032. You can check it by rightclick, SET CRS of layer. If you think that 4326 would be right, you can assign that to the layer and look if its situated better. Basic difference is that 23032 is in meters, and 4326 in degrees. EPSG:900913 and 3857 have the same definition, but the first is deprecated and will be cancelled in future versions of QGIS.

Comment: Thanks again, but still my layers are not in the right place. Coordinates are way of and still south of Nigeria. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your data. If it is really UTM, all x-values should be positive, and the y-values in Denmark should be greater than 6000000 (thats the distance from the aequator). So maybe the data is in another projection. Your shapefile should have a .prj file with SRS information. You can open it with any text editor. Maybe your data is in an older Danish local CRS, which is not known to QGIS.

Comment: Here is the .prj file: PROJCS["UTM_Zone_32_Northern_Hemisphere",GEOGCS["GCS_International 1909 (Hayford)",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["intl",6378388,297]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Comment: Transverse Mercator is not available for Denmark.

Comment: The prj file looks like ED50/UTM32N, but the extent you gave earlier does not fit to Denmark. I think you have to ask the people you got the data from if they can save it into another CRS, most likely WGS84 latlon. There was a CRS called "System 34" used in Denmark, but QGIS can not handle it.

Comment: Okay thanks, and thank you for your time. I'll ask my profesor tomorrow.